# My HMACSHA256 signature validation almost works but not quite

Tags: java, jwt, sha256, hmac

I wrote a method that takes a JWT as a request and checks if the signature is valid.

This is the unit test:

```
@Test
public void isValid() {
    final JwtValidator jwtValidator = JwtValidator.getInstance();
    final boolean valid = jwtValidator.isValid("eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiaWF0IjoxNTE2MjM5MDIyfQ.SflKxwRJSMeKKF2QT4fwpMeJf36POk6yJV_adQssw5c");
    Assert.isTrue(valid);
}
```

and this is the code:

```
@SneakyThrows
public boolean isValid(String extractedToken) {
    final String[] tokenParts = extractedToken.split(Pattern.quote("."));
    String header = tokenParts[0];
    String payload = tokenParts[1];
    String signature = tokenParts[2];

    final byte[] calcHmacSha256 = HMAC.calcHmacSha256("your-256-bit-secret".getBytes(), (header+"."+payload).getBytes());

    final String s = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(calcHmacSha256);

    System.out.println("'" + signature + "'.equals('"+s+"')");
    return signature.equals(s);
}
```

The log prints two strings that differ only for 2 chars, so I feel like I'm close "but not quite" to make it work:

```
'SflKxwRJSMeKKF2QT4fwpMeJf36POk6yJV_adQssw5c'.equals('SflKxwRJSMeKKF2QT4fwpMeJf36POk6yJV/adQssw5c=')
```

There are of course hard coded values because the implementation isn't complete, but I'm using the example values in https://jwt.io/ for ease of use right now.

Thanks!

**EDIT 1:**

```
public class JwtValidatorTest {

    @Test
    public void isValid() {
        byte[] header64 = Base64.getEncoder().encode("{\"alg\":\"HS256\",\"typ\":\"JWT\"}".getBytes());
        byte[] payload64 = Base64.getEncoder().encode("{\"sub\":\"1234567890\",\"name\":\"John Doe\",\"iat\":1516239022}".getBytes());

        final byte[] calcHmacSha256 = HMAC.calcHmacSha256("your-256-bit-secret".getBytes(), (header64+"."+payload64).getBytes());
        final String signature64 = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(calcHmacSha256);

        final String input = header64 + "." + payload64 + "." + signature64;

        final JwtValidator jwtValidator = JwtValidator.getInstance();

        final boolean valid = jwtValidator.isValid(input);
        
        Assert.isTrue(valid);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference is just caused by the different encoding used here. You used Base64 encoding, but the original signature is [Base64Url](https://base64.guru/standards/base64url) encoded. Base64Url encoding is, according to RFC7519, the [standard encoding for JWT](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-3):

> Each part contains a base64url-encoded value

Base64Url encoding has no padding (`=`) on the end and the characters `+` and `/` are replaced with `-`and `_`.

This code should solve the problem:

```
final String s = Base64.getUrlEncoder().withoutPadding().encodeToString(calcHmacSha256);
```

Comment: I cannot believe that the input data was "wrong"... I changed the test and edited the question. The test passes but do you mind checking if it's really correct?

Comment: maybe you misunderstood my answer. The original token as copied from jwt.io is correct (using base64url encoding) So you would need to change your validation method and also base64url encode the calculated signature as shown in my answer

Comment: Well, this token is used for server-to-server communication (ADFS - OAuth2 client credentials flow). In this case, the token is stored in the header and not passed in the URL, therefore I don't think that changing to a base64url makes sense in my case... or does it?

Comment: Tokens are usually transportet in the header, nonetheless the base64 encoding is just the standard encoding (see link in my answer). If you use a library to sign and to verify tokens (which I would recommend) then you always get base64 url encoded tokens. So just accept it as a standard.

Comment: I just want to point out that this code may still generate padding (=) at the end. Call `Base64.getUrlEncoder().withoutPadding().encodeToString(calcHmacSha256)` to generate the string without padding.